# Security issue in the from URL in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis

The webinspect scan report from the security team is reporting an issue with the URL. It says that when it passes any random number after a valid URL, the random number gets substitued as the value for the "action" attribute in the "form" tag.

Eg: 
If i request
_http:// myapplication /validpage.aspx/3242342

I get back the response, but the form tag's action attribute contains 3242342. My security team feels this is a vulnerability.

Can i know why the above URL does not throw a 404?
What needs to be done to handle this?
Or if it is the default behaviour of IIS and ASP.net, can somebody direct me to some site that says so.